# В равных условиях разная реакция. Почему?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Почему вот так вот не работает (выдает 404)

```
RewriteRule ^(company)/services/$ /company/branches.php [L]
```

Переименовываю папку company на company2. Делаю так.

```
RewriteRule ^(company)/services/$ /company2/branches.php [L]
```

И по той же самой ссылке (`example.dev/company/services/`) все прекрасно работает. Не первый раз уже такая проблема. Жутко раздражает. Что можно с этим сделать?

Дополнительные сведения:
Xdebug показал, что запроса к файлу /company/branches.php нет вообще. Он сразу идет показывать страницу 404. Права на чтение есть. Редиректов никаких не происходит.

Причем он ведет себя так, как будто файлов в этой папке вообще не существует... Что это может быть вообще?

P.S. Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Если скобки убрать `(company)`, то как себя ведет?

Comment: Так же.. если сделать 

`RewriteRule ^(company)/services2/$ /company/branches.php [L]`

И перейти по ссылке company/services2/ все будет работать. Причем на одном сервере под дебианом это работает нормально, а на другом под убунтой ничего не хочет отображать

Comment: У вас сухосин или ему подобные защиты не стоят на сервере?

Comment: Нет, не стоит. Из настроек сервера убрал  Options +MultiViews. Заработало почти все. Но теперь если я пытаюсь зайти по ссылке /services/ Выдает forbidden. То есть он пытается получить доступ к одноименной папке, вместо того, чтобы взглянуть на mod_rewrite и выдать мне нужную страницу. Что я опять сделал?

Comment: Все, достаточно было убрать MultiViews и все теперь работает.

Comment: @vtvz_ru напишите Ваше решение в качестве ответа на данный вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В ходе экспериментов методом тыка было выявлено, что за подобное нехорошее поведение отвечал параметр `Options +MultiViews`. [Гугление](http://webenterprise.ru/apache-multiviews/) показало, что из-за этой директивы сервер может выдавать всякие файлы и работать очень непредсказуемо, если ситема изначально не была спроектирована под это. Итого, обычное удаление этой строчки из конфига моего сервера решило все мои проблемы. Теперь понятно, почему он сервер обходил mod_rewrite и выдавал мне ошибку 404.